# refresh partial view onclick action button

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

so i have the next problem. I want to refresh only a partial view but it is't working. I tried to put two action on onclick but i need to push button 3 times to refresh.

here is my partian view

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>UserName</td>
        <td>FirstName</td>
        <td>LastName</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Rolul</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.users)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.UserID</td>
            <td>@item.UserName</td>
            <td>@item.FirstName</td>
            <td>@item.LastName</td>
            <td>@item.Email</td>
            <td>@item.RoleId</td>
            @if (item.RoleId == 2)
            {
                <td><input type="button" value="MakeAdmin" onclick="makeUserAdmin(@item.UserID);"/></td>
            }
            @if(item.RoleId==1)
            {
                <td><input type="button" value="RemoveAdmin" onclick="removeUserAdmin(@item.UserID);ShowTable('@Url.Action("UserTableView","User")" /></td>
            }

           @if (item.RoleId == 3)
           {
            <td><input type="button" disabled value="SuperAdmin" /></td>
           }
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

and here is my js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 function makeUserAdmin(userId) {
 $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/User/MakeAdmin',
    data: JSON.stringify
        ({
            userId: userId
        }),
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.Succes) {
                       alert("..");

        }
        else {
            alert(data.Errors[0]);
        }
    }

 });
}

function removeUserAdmin(userId) {

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/User/RemoveUserAdmin',
    data: JSON.stringify
        ({
            userId: userId
        }),
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.Succes) {

            alert("...");


        }
        else {
            alert(data.Errors[0]);
        }
    }
});
}
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you calling `ShowTable` twice while removing once in `html` and once again in `ajax success` and where is your `ShowTable` function?

Comment: where is your `ShowTable` function?

Comment: edited, sorry, just tried in onther way, isnt working..

Comment: Showtable function is in another js file. Ideea is that when i call function just in html i need to push 3 times on button to make refresh

Comment: So what's happening exactly? Can you please elaborate detailed functionality? It isn't clear with your question!

Comment: When i push removeUserAdmin, i want that partialview to refresh. I tried to put that ShowTable function in html and i need to push 3 times that button to refresh my page. I want to push just once, get that message that is success, and refresh that partian view

Comment: Any console errors... did you debug you code and check?

Comment: Yes i debugged my code. I checked no errors..

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem:

```
function makeUserAdmin(button, userId) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/User/MakeAdmin',
    data: JSON.stringify
        ({
            userId: userId
        }),
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.Success) {
            console.log($(button));
            $(button).attr('onclick', 'removeUserAdmin(this,' + userId + ')');
            $(button).val("RemoveAdmin");
            alert("..");
        }
        else {
            alert(data.Errors[0]);
        }
    }
});


function removeUserAdmin(button, userId) {

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/User/RemoveUserAdmin',
    data: JSON.stringify
        ({
            userId: userId
        }),
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.Success) {
            console.log($(button));
            $(button).attr('onclick', 'makeUserAdmin(this,' + userId + ')');
            $(button).val("MakeAdmin");
            alert("...");
        }
        else {
            alert(data.Errors[0]);
        }
    }
});
```